# jquery datepicker set default date to empty string

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to hide the initial text that the datepicker display. I do not want the user to see any text in the textbox, unless he selects the date ?

Comment: The very first example in the documentation does not have any initial value: http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can hide the initial text that the date-picker shows.

Take a flag that will check that date select or not and on the behalf of that make the textbox   text clear.

Comment: sorry, but what you want to say exactly.